# Just installed Sure Vent is not working and sink is clogged. What did I do wrong?

Tags: plumbing, vent

Just installed a Sure Vent underneath our kitchen island sink. I added the T and 5-6 inch of pipe between the T and the sure vent.

Now water is filling up the sink and the sure vent pipe.

What did I do wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you stuff a rag in the pipe to prevent smells or possibly dribbled some pipe cement in the drain and it spread over the water in the trap made a plastic plug I have seen that before.

Comment: Nope but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Draino will dissolve a rag LOL

Comment: The sanitary Tee in your photo is installed **UPSIDE DOWN**. The curve should be going down to drain, not up to   vent.

Comment: @alaskaman I didn't realize there was a side to install it. Do you think it's worth redoing it? Seems to work fine now but ...

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue was the drain blocked. The Surevent was properly installed and just exposed even further the fact that our drain was clogged. A full bottle Drano and a few dead dolphins later we are good to go.